# What is a range of an attribute in data mining?

Tags: data-mining, data-sets

In my data mining course, we are working with a data set. I have to identity the ranges of each attribute. I am given the set of data for all 150 points and i am given the visualization (charts) of all attributes. However I do not know how to use that set of data or the charts to find the ranges of each attribute. I do not know what is meant by range either.

I'm working on the data set for Iris plants and I have three classes of the flower.

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information, however it looks like the attribute $A$ range is interval $[A_{min}, A_{max}]$

Comment: There is a thing they call a *dictionary*. It tells you a lot about the meaning of words.

Answer (score 0):

The range of the attribute is the interval where the values of the attribute varies. For Real numbers, is the closed interval [min,max].

For example, for an attribute $A$ with values $\{0.1, 0.5 , 1 , 10 , 100\}$ the range is the interval $[0.1,100]$

The concept is also valid for Integers, however there are no widely know notation to describe that. Ways of describing it would be:

$i = 1,...,10$

or

$(i \in \mathbb{Z}) \wedge (i \in [0,10])$